# Azure DevOps Server (On-prem) Permission to Everyone

Tags: permissions, azure-devops-server

Would be great if someone can clarify this.

We are using Azure DevOps 2020 Server (On-prem). We have a team project that contains only Wiki, other services are disabled. Is there a way to grant permission to **EVERYONE** in a organization instead of adding user or AD group.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to grant permission to EVERYONE in a organization

As far as I know, when a user is added to an Organization/Collection, the user will be added to `Project Collection Valid Users` Group by default.

You could grant the permission to this group.

Then the users in the organization/collection will have the permission to view wiki.

[image]